# Clicking an item on a drop-down menu with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble clicking an item on a drop-down menu with VBA. I am able to click the drop-down button to show the options, but I cant click on a specific item. Below is the item I want to click on.

```
<a class="ActiveLink" title="Excel" alt="Excel" 
onclick="$find('ctl31').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" 
href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; 
white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">Excel</a>
```

There are 5 possible selections in the dropdown. "title" and "alt" are unique to this selection.  The "class" is unique to all items of the dropdown.  I tried the following.

```
 IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ActiveLink")(4).Click
```

I am aware that the 4 indicates the 5th element.

The error is

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I have resolved with the following code.

```
Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document

For Each l In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
   If l.Title = "Excel" Then
       l.Click
       Exit For
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Do you get an error?  If Yes, what is it?

Comment: ^^As above and also is there an URL to share? Please show more of the HTML. Are you aware that indexing starts at 0 so the 4th element would be at (3) ?

Comment: I am aware that the 4 indicates the 5th element.  The error i am receiving is Object doesn't support this property or method.  Thanks.